# Regex: pulling out many substrings between tags repeated many times

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split, substring

I have a data in the format:

```
CODE FIRSTTYPE: [DATA OF FIRST TYPE] SECONDTYPE: [DATA OF SECOND TYPE]
```

I would like to split this up to look like this:

```
CODE
FIRSTYPE:
DATA OF FIST TYPE 
SECONDTYPE: 
DATA OF SECOND TYPE
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I tried this one:

```
(\[\s*(((?!\[|\]).)+)\s*\])
```

But it seems to do only once, and also removes the other words.

Comment: Sorry, just edited my post telling the closest data I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that is based on matching the texts between square brackets or non-whitespace sequences into capturing groups:

```
String str = "CODE FIRSTTYPE: [DATA OF FIRST TYPE] SECONDTYPE: [DATA OF SECOND TYPE]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]|(\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = r.matcher(str);
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) == null)
       arr.add(matcher.group(2));
    else
        arr.add(matcher.group(1));
}
// PRINT FOR DEMO
String[] simpleArray = new String[arr.size()];
arr.toArray(simpleArray);
for (String s : simpleArray) { System.out.println(s); }
```

Here is  [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8K5ar7)

The regex is

```
\[([^\]]*)\]|(\S+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF1zL0/1)

Comment: I have realized that the code can be shortened, as the alternatives are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

**This works if the format remains the same:**

```
String name="CODE FIRSTTYPE: [DATA OF FIRST TYPE] SECONDTYPE: [DATA OF SECOND TYPE]";
Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s(\\w+:)\\s\\[([\\w+\\s]*)\\]\\s(\\w+:)\\s\\[([\\w+\\s]*)\\]");
Matcher mat=pat.matcher(name);
while(mat.find()){
    System.out.println(mat.group(1));
    System.out.println(mat.group(2));
    System.out.println(mat.group(3));
    System.out.println(mat.group(4));
    System.out.println(mat.group(5));
}
```

Comment: This was useful, but the CODE is composed by Characters, numbers and sometimes special characters, and this one is picking only the numbers